# Authenticatnig ASP.NET MVC application against Sitecore users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, asp.net-identity

I just started to working in Sitecore. I am developing a web application in ASP.NET MVC 5.0 to create / edit some content in Sitecore. I am looking for the best way for authentication in web application (MVC) using existing Sitecore users. User management part will stay with Sitecore, just need authentication (login) in web application against Sitecore users. Can I use Identity concept of ASP.NET for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this in the last few weeks.

What you will need first to to create a Role in Sitecore that your Extranet (siteusers) will get logged in against.  Create a user and assign them to this role.

You will need to go to the security editor (i think) and select the 'everyone' role.  Allow everything and inheritance from the top of the tree. (green cross on the content item)

For the item you wish to lock put a red cross against the inheritance

Then select your created role and put a green cross in inheritance against the item you wish to allow this role to see

From Sitecore: The idea is allow everything for everyone and break inheritance to secure it by adding a red cross to inheritance.

From the website: The idea is that everyone (siteusers) don't have access to the page and will get redirected.  People in your new role will go to the page.

Next take a look at the post above but in your site settings you need a configure the location of your login page.

After these steps you should be able to navigate to the page and get redirected to your login page (Make sure you are not in the content editor)(incog mode google chrome)

So finally you can use the Sitecore.Authentication namespace and there are method on there to authenticate and check if a user is in a role ect.

Take a look at https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/security_api_cookbook_usletter.pdf

Hope this helps.  Any questions just ask.  Its hard to explain in text :)

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore use Membership providers.
Normally create for web users a new domain. so not the same as CMS users.

See This:
http://fes-sitecore.blogspot.nl/2015/02/using-membership-with-sitecore.html

And the Documentation from Sitecore:
https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/membership_providers_a4.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Aki,

You can leverage the sitecore authentication which is very useful, I am using this in my all projects since sitecore 6.5 to 7.5.

you just have to explore few APIs of sitecore membership, there you will get

1. How to create roles
2. how to set users in roles.
3. And how to provide proper security or limited access to a particular role.
4. How to set custom data for users also.

Make sure you are not using sitecore domain for web users, use extranet domain. Sitecore domain is only for user who are supposed to login into sitecore dashboard.

Hope this will help you..

Cheers!!